# Keep PHPMailler connection alive over Laravel's queue

Tags: laravel

I want to send many emails.
Currently I write basic code use PHPMailler to send mail using queue. It works, but everytime new queue is run, it have to connect to SMTP again, so i get bad perfomance.

I find SMTPKeepAlive property on PHPMailler documentation:

```
$phpMailer = New PHPMailer();    
$phpMailer->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
```

Is it imposible and how to keep $phpMailler object for next queue? So PHPMailler have not to connect again by using previous connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel then you have to use Laravel's feature inbuilt.

Please find below documents:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail

Please find a piece of code for send mail and adding in a queue:

```
use App\Mail\EmailVerifyMail;
\Mail::queue(new EmailVerifyMail($users));
```

**EmailVerifyMail.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class EmailVerifyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this->to($this->user)->subject(__('mail.subjects.verification_link', ['USERNAME' => $this->user->name]));
        return $this->view('mails/emailVerify', ['user' => $this->user]);
    }
}
```